# Why does a compile-time error appears for this one involving Generics?

Tags: java, generics

For the following 2 classes detailed below:

```
class Gen<T> {
    T ob;

    Gen(T o) {
       ob = o;
    }

    // Return ob.
    T getob() {
         return ob;
    }
}

class Gen2<T> extends Gen<T> {
    Gen2(T o) {
        super(o);
    }
}

class HierDemo3 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

         // Create a Gen2 object for Integers.
         Gen2<Integer> iOb2 = new Gen2<Integer>(99);

         if(iOb2 instanceof Gen2<Integer>) //compile-time error
                System.out.println("iOb2 is instance of Gen2<Integer>");
    }
 }
```

I know very well that it will compile for:

```
     iOb2 instanceof Gen2<?>
```

Sounds like there is no generic type information available at run time. If so, when is it made available? I am confused...

Comment: It sounds like you're already aware that generics undergo type erasure when compiled.  If so, what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of compilation, [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) occurs, and type information such as this is not present in the generated bytecode.  This occurs because Java needs to maintain backwards compatibility with code that was written pre-Generics.  The JVM has no notion of generics.

> Generics were introduced to the Java language to provide tighter type checks at compile time and to support generic programming. To implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure to:
>
> - Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.
> - Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.
> - Generate bridge methods to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.
>   Type erasure ensures that no new classes are created for parameterized types; consequently, generics incur no runtime overhead.

The `instanceof` operator is inherently a runtime operation, so it cannot determine what the generic type parameter is, so the compiler must disallow generic types for `instanceof`.

Using `Gen2<?>` or just `Gen2` is the best you can do at runtime.